# Breast milk with reverse osmosis

Tags: osmosis

I would like to make life lasting breast milk jewelry. I would need at least 5ml to make it. I've been doing a lot of research to get the best results, so far this questions are the result of more than a year trying to get the right answer. Would reverse osmosis remove each bacteria from it, allowing me to work with it in resin without using harsh chemicals and not molding inside the resin? How much ml of breast milk would I need to have at least 5ml after the process is done? I would need to make it into a powder after the process, which I think it could be achieved either with silica gel, or dry by the sun. What would you suggest? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to remove all the moisture content from a small sample on the order of a few mL I suggest using a lyophilizer. It should leave the solutes found in milk largely chemically unaltered. The high sugar and low water content should also serve to preserve the dry product (similarly to [powdered milk](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Powdered_milk)). The dry product can be resuspended as needed by vortexing in an appropriate volume of distilled water. [Typical solids concentration in human breast milk is ~10%](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/392766/).

An alternative is to isolate the milk curds (the protein fraction) by acidifying the milk, by adding for instance vinegar. You can then make casein plastic from the curds (there are many suggestions on how to do this online, and this was one [source of plastics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Galalith) before synthetics became the norm). The acid treatment should serve as a germicidal step. You should be aware that protein content in human breast milk is approximately 3 times lower than in bovine milk (~1% versus 3%, respectively). This means that you will need roughly 3 times the volume of human milk, assuming the casein fraction is the same in both, to make the same amount of casein plastic.

Depending on whether you intend to use all of the solids or only the protein fraction of the milk, you will need (ignoring differences in density) different volumes of milk to obtain 5 mL of solids: about 50 mL of milk to make 5 mL of complete solids, and ten times more, ~500 mL of milk, to make 5 mL of protein extract. I recommend testing with bovine milk first and then using the relative solid or protein concentrations described in the references to determine the required volume of human milk.

Comment: There are tutorials about home-made galalith, like this one (based on animal milk) https://www.wikihow.com/Make-"Plastic"-out-of-Milk Eventually this would require some downscaling, of course.